# Zendframework getUploadedFiles() empty

Tags: php, zend-framework

**Hi everyone,**

I am trying to make a `api` request to an `api` that I made. All the `api` does is uploading files to the server. I use the [zendframework](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-diactoros) to do this. I made a function that handles the request and my problem is the following:

```
$files = $this->getRequest()->getUploadedFiles();
```

Returns nothing, the array stays empty, but the when I print the body of the request I can see the file in there. Why does it stay empty?

I use `postman` to create the request.

I hope someone can help me since I wasn't able to find a thread with the same problem posted in it.

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Which PHP version? There are some potential "quirks" with ZF1 and PHP 7 - turn on all error reporting and see if something is dying.

Comment: @CD001 thanks for your comment. We only use zend-diactoros. Can we still get potential quirks with that?

Comment: Actually you might be alright - I was thinking of the Varien file uploader in Magento (Magento sits on top of Varien and ZF1) there are some syntax issues with the Varien file uploader with PHP 7.

Answer (score 0):

*It's a bit late, but might help those who are currently facing this problem:*

Include this line in your view template (.phtml) before you open form tag

> $form->prepare()

Or instead you can try adding the form's enctype manually.

Full Example:

```
<!-- File: upload-form.phtml -->
<?php
    $form->prepare(); // The correct enctype is set here
    $fileElement = $form->get('image-file');
    echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
?>

    <div class="form-element">
        <?= $this->formLabel($fileElement) ?>
        <?= $this->formFile($fileElement) ?>
        <?= $this->formElementErrors($fileElement) ?>
    </div>

    <button>Submit</button>

<?= $this->form()->closeTag() ?>
```

Source: https://docs.laminas.dev/laminas-form/file-upload/